# Cut colum in two same sized pieces, once one colum needs more space should expand

Tags: flutter, dart

The bottom section (white background), should have 60 percent of the screen height and the top section (light grey background) should have 40 percent of the screen height. In case the content of the bottom section gets bigger than 60 percent of the device height, the bottom section should expand and the top section should shrink.

[image]

Here you can see the problem we ran into with fixed flex values (Overflow at the bottom).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in various ways! First of all, you can try [`FractionallySizedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) which does exactly what you're looking for.

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: 0.6, // 60% of the available height
  widthFactor: 0.3,  // 30% of the available width
  child: const MyWidget()
)
```

If you're inside a `Row` or `Column`, put it inside a `Flexible` widget to not get troubles. Alternatively, you can use a LayoutBuilder which is more powerful as it gives you more data about the available space:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    final myWidth = constraints.maxWidth * 0.6;
   
    return Container(
      width: myWidth,
      child: const MyChild(),
    );
  }
);
```

You should use `LayoutBuilder` to create responsive UIs because it takes into account the **available** space (so potential paddings or margins are considered). Finally, you can use `MediaQuery`:

```
final myWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6
```

However, `MediaQuery` refers to the physical size of the screen so it doesn't take into account the actual available space on the UI (but `LayoutBuilder` does).

---

I'd suggest you to try with `FractionallySizedBox` first and then go for `LayoutBuilder` if you're in trouble.

I'd also suggest avoiding the usage of `MediaQuery` because it will always return the SAME values for width and height (since it relies on your device's size). Instead, `LayoutBuilder` computes the actual remaining space taking into account other widgets as well.